# How to make the kotlin function with List<> callable from Java

Tags: java, android, arraylist, kotlin

In kotlin has MyClass with List member,  and the builder has function to take the List<Data>.

but in Java code when it calls the builder's  `fun dataList(dataList: List<Data>)` it gets compiler error something about

`List<> cannot be applied to ArrayList<>`.

From the decompiled code it shows the list is type of `kotlin.collections.List<>`.

How to make the function with List<> callable from Java?

```
data class MyClass( 
    val context: Context,
    val dataList: List<Data> = emptyList<Data>(),
) {

    private constructor(builder: Builder) : this(builder.context, builder.dataList)

    class Builder {
        private var context: Context? = null
        private var dataList: List<Data> = emptyList<Data>()

        fun context(context: Context) = apply { this.context = context }
        fun dataList(dataList: List<Data>) = apply { this.dataList = dataList }

        fun build() = MyClass(this)
    }
}
```

in JAVA

```
ArrayList<Data> theDataList = new ArrayList<Data>();
theDataList.add(new Data())

MyClass myClass = new MyClass.Builder()
            .context(appContext)
            .dataList(theDataList)  //<== error
            .build();
```

the error is :

```
dataList(Java.util.List<com.model.Data>)  in Builder  cannot be applied to dataList(Java.util.ArrayList<com.model.Data>)
```

and in Java code if clicking on the dataList()  it opens the decompiled code as below, and seems it complains about the

`fun dataList(dataList: kotlin.collections.List<com.model.Data>)`:

```
public final data class Data public constructor(context: android.content.Context, 
         dataList: kotlin.collections.List<com.model.Data> /* = compiled code */) {

    public final val context: android.content.Context /* compiled code */
    public final val dataList: kotlin.collections.List<com.model.Data> /* compiled code */

    public final operator fun component1(): android.content.Context { /* compiled code */ }
    public final operator fun component2(): kotlin.collections.List<com.model.Data> { /* compiled code */ }


    public final class Builder public constructor() {

       private final var context: android.content.Context? /* compiled code */
       private final var dataList: kotlin.collections.List<com.model.Data> /* compiled code */

       ... ...
       public final fun dataList(dataList: kotlin.collections.List<com.model.Data>): com.model.MyClass.Builder { /* compiled code */ }

       ... ...
       public final fun build(): com.model.Data { /* compiled code */ }


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
ArrayList<Data> theDataList = new ArrayList<Data>();
```

you should use:

```
List<Data> theDataList = new ArrayList<Data>();
```